# QTableView has unwanted checkboxes in every cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qtwidgets

I'm trying to make a simple tabular data layout using a `QTableView` with a model class of my own creation inheriting from `QAbstractTableModel`. For some reason, my table view ends up looking like this:

[image]

<sub>(source: [nerdland.net](http://users.nerdland.net/tyler/files/pics/qtableview_checkboxes.png))</sub>

What in the heck are those things that look like checkboxes (but don't do anything when I click them) in every cell, and how do I make them go away? I haven't changed any of the `QTableView` properties except for the object's name.

If it matters, my model code is dead simple:

```cpp
MyTableModel::MyTableModel(QObject* parent)
  : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

MyTableModel::~MyTableModel()
{
}

int MyTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
  return 1000; 
}

int MyTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
  return 5;
}

QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
  return "Foo";
}
```

The dialog UI is built in Qt Designer, and inside the class for the dialog I attach the model to the view like this:

```cpp
MyTableModel testModel = new MyTableModel(this);
ui.testTable->setModel(testModel);
```

Other than that, I perform no operations on `ui.testTable`.

Using Qt 4.6.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try changing `MyTableModel::data()` to the following:

```
QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return "foo";
    else
        return QVariant();
}
```

Probably the returned QVariant for role `Qt::CheckStateRole` was misunderstood by the QTableView.

Answer (score 2):

Do you by any chance happen to set the [Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) flag in [flags()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags)?

Comment: No, and even if I override `flags` to return ` QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) & ~Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;`, the checkboxes remain.